# How do I vertically align line items having text and an image?

Tags: asp.net-core, bootstrap-4, html-lists, vertical-alignment

I have text and an image in menu items made up of ul and li tags. I am using default _layout.cshtml page. I want to vertically align the text of menu items. But instead they are aligned at the top.

I tried vertical-align attribute on #li tags.

```
<style>
    li#menu-item-logo a {
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    li#menu-item-logo a img{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
</style>
```

Entire _Layout.cshatml content:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - Badar Books</title>

    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute"
              crossorigin="anonymous"
              integrity="sha256-eSi1q2PG6J7g7ib17yAaWMcrr5GrtohYChqibrV7PBE=" />
    </environment>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <style>
        li#menu-item-logo a {
            line-height: 30px;
        }
        li#menu-item-logo a img{
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse align-text-bottom">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item" id="menu-item-logo">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index" name="homepage">
                                <img src="~/images/BadarBooks_Monogram.png" alt="Badar Books Monogram" class="img-responsive" />
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Index" name="home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/About">ABOUT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Contact">CONTACT</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Catalogs">CATALOGS</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Search">SEARCH</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/SalesAndShipping">SALES AND SHIPPING</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>

    <footer class="border-top footer text-muted">
        <div class="container">
            &copy; 2019 - Badar Books - <a asp-area="" asp-page="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <environment include="Development">
        <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=">
        </script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
                asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                crossorigin="anonymous"
                integrity="sha256-E/V4cWE4qvAeO5MOhjtGtqDzPndRO1LBk8lJ/PR7CA4=">
        </script>
    </environment>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Let me know if I should post site.css file contents. The project was created using VS21017 ASP.NET Core 2.2 Web Application template.

The output:

The menu items are at the top. I need them in the middle.

menu items with an image menu item

[image: screenshots]

Comment: Please include the html for the whole row, including the logo. I assume you want text middle-aligned with the logo?

Comment: Yes. I want to middle-align text menus with the image. I will post the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="logo.png" /></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Catalogs</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Dropdown
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```